# C# WebApi incoming client certificate always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to debug an issue with incoming requests never having a client certificate attached to them.

I'm fairly certain the request has a client certificate, I have test code that runs against two possible end points (one ours, one on a third party service), running common code to attach the certificate to the request and the SSL negotiation works fine against the third party service.

I'm having the same issue with IISExpress (VS2010), as well as on IIS 8.

The cert is installed and trusted on both machines.

I've tried the steps here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api with no luck.

I've tried both these ways to access the certificate, both in a custom ActionFilter

```
var cert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;

var certificate = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
```

Is it possibly the context of the ActionFilter vs a DelegatingHandler causing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried configure IIS to require client certificate?

Comment: Haven't tried requiring it, but that won't work since only one real action plus the testing one work with the client certificate.

I've tried with this in the config, but no luck.

<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />

Answer (score 0):

What does your client code look like? Are you attaching a client certificate to your `WebRequestHandler`?

It shouldn't matter if you use an ActionFilter vs a DelegatingHanlder but I would recommend using a `DelegatingHandler` because it occurs before the controller context is created and will be more performant (will reject unauthorized requests earlier).

Comment: It's using an HttpWebRequest object on the outgoing calls, and the certificate is definitely attached.  I can see it as part of the request object before it does the actual POST request.

The third party service is also receiving the certificate and validating against it (I've confirmed this by commenting out the code and seeing the SSL/TLS handshake fail).

I'm using the ActionFilter because it's only one real (and one test) action that is being authenticated this way.  I definitely agree in general the Handler is more ideal if it would always need to validate though.

Comment: ActionFilter sounds great then. Sounds like there's an issue with the server configuration then if another server can receive the certificate. You could try requiring a client cert with  `<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslRequireCert" />` in your web server config. Also I would try adding a private key to your client certificate and signing the request with that.

Comment: Is it possibly a trust or permission issue with the cert?  I'm thinking no since it gets attached to the request, but might be worth pursuing.  I'm not doing extensive (or any at this point) validation, just checking for the presence of any cert.

The cert is in the root trusted folder as well as the personal store.

Comment: I have used self-signed client certificates with inherent trust issues and have used `Request.GetClientCertificate()` to view them on the server side. In this instance I also had turned off the X509CertificateValidator with this code: `HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("localhost"); // tell the system that the server requires client cert
config.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
// turn off the built in certificate authentication
 config.X509CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None;` I don't know how you're hosting the server

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter where you are getting the certificate. Make sure the certificates are in their correct places especially the CA issuer certificate. That should be in the Trusted CA folder for your *Local Machine*. You can use OpenSSL to troubleshoot this, and see if the certificates are causing issues.

One issue that is very common is during the handshake, the server sends a list of trusted CAs, but there is a limit so if you have a lot of trusted CAs some of them will be truncated. Thus, the client never sends a certificate. You can try to clean the Trusted Authorities folder up, but make sure you don't remove any important CAs that are mandatory. An alternative is adding an entry into your registry editor to not allow the server to send a list of the trusted CAs. [You can read more here](http://www.codit.eu/blog/2013/04/03/troubleshooting-ssl-client-certificate-issue-on-iis/).

Also, if you're using IIS, you don't need to use selfhost.